# Sqlalchemy from_self in an inner query referencing outer aliased table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy query like this:

```
E = aliased(Entity, name='e')
db.session.query(E) \
    .filter(E.user_id == user_id) \
    .filter(
        db.session.query(Entity) \
            .distinct(Entity.original_id) \
            .order_by(Entity.original_id, Entity.id.desc())
            .filter(Entity.ref_id == E.ref_id) \
            .from_self(Entity.flag) \
            .order_by(Entity.timestamp.desc()) \
            .limit(1).as_scalar()
    ) \
    .order_by(E.timestamp) \
    .all()
```

It produces (roughly) the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM entity AS e
WHERE e.user_id = 1 AND (
    SELECT anon_1.entity_flag AS flag
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (entity.original_id)
            entity.flag AS entity_flag, entity.timestamp AS entity_timestamp
        FROM entity, entity AS e # THIS "entity AS e" SHOULD NOT BE HERE
        WHERE
            entity.ref_id = e.ref_id
            ORDER BY entity.original_id, entity.id DESC
    ) AS anon_1
    ORDER BY anon_1.entity_timestamp
    LIMIT 1
) ORDER BY e.timestamp;
```

Because it somehow adds `entity AS e` into the inner query `FROM` clause it causes the `WHERE entity.ref_id = e.ref_id` not to reference the outer table as it should.

Why is this extraneous `entity AS e` added to the inner `FROM` clause and how to overcome it?

Comment: Could you provide a model definition for `Entity` so that it's easier to play around with your query?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. It has `id`, `ref_id`, `timestamp`, `original_id`, `user_id` and `flag` columns. `flag` is boolean.

Comment: What I meant is that the people answering are lazy (I am, at least), but might want to try running and tweaking your query, but now have to come up with the model definition based on how it's used in your query, which takes time and might shy some people away. So in order to help people help you, it's usually better to provide a complete, and verifiable example, i.e. something that's pretty much usable with minimum effort.

Comment: The why is probably related to the fact that SQLA's autocorrelation picks FROM objects from the immediate enclosing query only. If you want to correlate up from deeper nesting, explicit correlation is required. Not entirely sure, but maybe the auto aliasing done by `Query.from_self()` is also affecting the result.

Comment: "explicit correlation is required" - how do I do that?

Comment: [`Query.correlate()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.correlate) would be the answer normally, but for some reason I couldn't make it work in your case. Still looking into it. Autocorrelation's behaviour is explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.correlate) (and probably elsewhere as well). It has something to do with the fact that you're referring to the alias in a subsubquery. Works for a simple subquery as it should.

Answer (score 5):

It might be that you've found the limits of [`Query.from_self()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self):

> The automatic aliasing feature only works in a **limited** way, for simple filters and orderings. More ambitious constructions such as referring to the entity in joins should prefer to use explicit subquery objects, typically making use of the [`Query.subquery()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) method to produce an explicit subquery object. Always test the structure of queries by viewing the SQL to ensure a particular structure does what’s expected!

In general SQLAlchemy's "auto-correlation" considers FROM objects for correlation from the [immediate enclosing query only](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.correlate) and if deeper levels of nesting are required, explicit correlation must be used.

On the other hand, in your case this does not help. Adding a call to [`Query.correlate()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.correlate) does not break through the boundary of `Query.from_self()` for some reason, though using them together is even mentioned in the documentation:

> The correlation arguments take effect in such cases as when `Query.from_self()` is used, or when a subquery as returned by `Query.subquery()` is embedded in another `select()` construct.

A solution is to use explicit subqueries:

```
In [65]: sq = session.query(Entity.flag, Entity.timestamp).\
    ...:     distinct(Entity.original_id).\
    ...:     order_by(Entity.original_id, Entity.id.desc()).\
    ...:     filter(Entity.ref_id == E.ref_id).\
    ...:     correlate(E).\
    ...:     subquery()

In [66]: q = session.query(E).\
    ...:     filter(E.user_id == 123).\
    ...:     filter(session.query(sq.c.flag).
    ...:            order_by(sq.c.timestamp.desc()).
    ...:            limit(1).
    ...:            as_scalar()).\
    ...:     order_by(E.timestamp)
    ...:            

In [67]: print(q.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
SELECT e.id, e.ref_id, e.timestamp, e.original_id, e.user_id, e.flag 
FROM entity AS e 
WHERE e.user_id = %(user_id_1)s AND (SELECT anon_1.flag 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (entity.original_id) entity.flag AS flag, entity.timestamp AS timestamp 
FROM entity 
WHERE entity.ref_id = e.ref_id ORDER BY entity.original_id, entity.id DESC) AS anon_1 ORDER BY anon_1.timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s) ORDER BY e.timestamp
```