# Sqlalchemy nested query with correlation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the followning psql query which I would like to translate to `sqlalchemy`

```sql
SELECT
    i.fingerprint1,
    i.fingerprint2,
    time_bucket('10 minute', i.timestamp) as bucket
FROM impression i
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM
        impression
    WHERE
        fingerprint1 = i.fingerprint1 AND
        fingerprint2 = i.fingerprint2
) > 1
GROUP BY
    i.fingerprint1,
    i.fingerprint2,
    bucket
```

My attempt:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
I = aliased(Impression, name='i')

impression_bucket = func.time_bucket("1 minute", getattr(Impression,  "timestamp")).label("date")

inner = (
    db.session.query(I)
        .with_entities(func.count())
        .filter(
            Impression.fingerprint1 == I.fingerprint1,
            Impression.fingerprint2 == I.fingerprint2
        ).correlate(I).subquery()
)

outer = (
    db.session.query(I)
    .with_entities(
        I.fingerprint1,
        I.fingerprint2,
        impression_bucket
    )
    .filter(inner.as_scalar() > 1)
    .group_by(
        I.fingerprint1,
        I.fingerprint2,
        impression_bucket
    )
)
```

Which produces:

```sql
SELECT
    i.fingerprint1 AS i_fingerprint1,
    i.fingerprint2 AS i_fingerprint2, time_bucket(%(time_bucket_1)s,
    impression.timestamp) AS date 
FROM impression AS i, impression 
WHERE (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
    FROM
        impression 
    WHERE
        impression.fingerprint1 = i.fingerprint1 AND impression.fingerprint2 = i.fingerprint2
    ) > %(param_1)s
GROUP BY
    i.fingerprint1,
    i.fingerprint2,
    time_bucket(%(time_bucket_1)s, impression.timestamp)

{'time_bucket_1': '1 minutes', 'param_1': 1}
```

The line `FROM impression AS i, impression` should be `FROM impression AS i`. How can I modift the sqlalchemy query to achieve this?

I have also looked at [Sqlalchemy from_self in an inner query referencing outer aliased table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480518/sqlalchemy-from-self-in-an-inner-query-referencing-outer-aliased-table) which helped with `correlate`

N.B `time_bucket` is a timescaledb function which is why I haven't supplied a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You have a nice and readable query in a standard language. Run it in sqlalchemy as native. Why shall you scramble it into cryptic proprietary method calls that exorcistically try to express declarative logic in  imperative terms, virtually impossible to even read least to test?

Comment: In PG14 you can use [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function to emulate `time_bucket`. A `date_bin` implementation for versions prior to 14 can be found [here](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Pre-PG14-date_bin-function).